# Method names and the use of "from" and "with"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, naming-conventions

Does using "From" or "With" in a method name mean anything?

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];

[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index];
```

If so I would guess that "With" retains and "From" does not, but I have never heard any discussion on this.

If not why have a difference in the way the methods are named? Would it not mean the same thing if they both had "With" or both had "From"

Comment: it does not have any meaning other than semanthic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesnt mean anything, just helps to make the methods more readable and human friendly.